# Browsers send Authorization header only for constrained pages- How does it know?

Tags: java, jsp, http, servlets, basic-authentication

I have a sample application where few of the pages have security constraint.
(Total 5 pages. Secured 2 pages)

I was watching the request/response sets in Fiddler and was surprised!

Even after BASIC authorisation is completed, the browser is sending Authorisation header only for my constrained pages.
**How does the browser know which pages in an application are constrained?**

I am wondering if browser does one of the below:

1. Does the browser do a HEAD request before each GET? Is this how it finds if the page being navigated to is constrained?
2. Does the browser assume url pattern like "all pages in the same folder as the url that was responsible for the 401"?

Comment: Inspect the requests in Firefox Firebug plugin or any other plugins.

Comment: I'm inspecting http requests using Fiddler. I'm browsing with Chrome and IE11 and seeing the raw request/response in Fiddler. Would it be any better to use Firebug?

Comment: As I know if I access `https` page from `http` page then an extra cookie `path=/;secure` is added.

Comment: I'm not using https as of now as it is a test application. So, all pages are on http.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it cannot know. But it can cache the fact that at last visit, the server asked for authentication. To control that, you should :

- clear all in browser (cookies, history, cache)
- stop it and start it again (to make sure you start with a *clean* browser)
- only **then** inspect requests and responses

You should see two consecutive requests for each secured page *at first time*, first getting a 401 *Unauthorized* response, and second carrying authentication headers. And on following requests on same page, the browser remembers the page requires authentication and directly sends the header, without sending them for other pages.

So it does not guess, but only remembers which pages requires authentication headers.

Comment: I did try with a new browser to prevent caching. Anyway, I'll check again. Even with the above approach, it would mean that the browser tries all secured links without authorization header atleast once and gets 401 and then remembers to send the header from next time onwards. Why should the browser try without that header once for every link? So many secured links will return 401 atleast once. Is there something we are missing?